# SQL. Filter null fields in resonse

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table users, with fields: id, name, age, gender, country, city, comment. Fields maybe null. For example:

```
cursor.execute('select * from users where id = 12')
cursor.fetchone()
(12, 'alex', 33, 'male', None, None, None)
```

How I can get back from query only not null fields?

This query must return me just

```
(12, 'alex', 33, 'male')
```

I can easily do it with a programming language, but I losing my resources by getting redundant info from tables and it also forced me to add redundant code.

Comment: You can't filter columns dynamically in SQL.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? How will you know which columns were filtered out?

Comment: By the order. Anyway I'm don't getting answer in key=value format

Comment: But if there are null columns in the middle, it changes the order.

Answer (score 0):

So, you need to get customized table-oriented result with columns dynamically generated with **SQL ANSI.** 
You will need a kit with two procedures:

1. Check if a column has only NULL values or not.
2. Gather all columns with NO NULL values.

With these two procedures you can check each column of a table strcuture and get an output withtout columns with NULL values.

The first procedure is generic:

```
set delimiter //

create procedure check_field_null(col varchar(64), 
                                  schemaname varchar(255),
                                  tablename varchar(255), 
                                  out QN int)
BEGIN
   SET @sSQL = concat('SELECT  @N := COUNT(*) FROM ', schemaname, '.', tablename , ' WHERE (', col, ' <=> NULL);');
   prepare stm from @sSQL;
   execute stm;
   set QN =@N;
   deallocate prepare stm;

END
//
```

The second procedure means that you have the above mentioned method to identify NOT NULLS columns and put all to search.

```
set delimiter //
create procedure cur_cs_customer(inout allcols varchar(255), in my_schema_name varchar(64), in my_table_name varchar(64))
BEGIN
 DECLARE Count_Null  int default 0;
 DECLARE initial INT DEFAULT 0;
 DECLARE MYCOL   char(64);
 DECLARE ch_done INT DEFAULT 0;
 DECLARE cs_cur1 CURSOR 
         FOR SELECT C.COLUMN_NAME
             FROM information_schema.COLUMNS C
             WHERE C.TABLE_SCHEMA = my_schema_name
               AND C.TABLE_NAME = my_table_name;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET ch_done = true;

open cs_cur1;

read_cs_cur1:
LOOP
    FETCH cs_cur1 INTO MYCOL;

    IF (ch_done ) THEN
        LEAVE read_cs_cur1;
    END IF;

    IF NOT isnull(MYCOL) THEN

        call check_field_null(MYCOL, 
                              my_schema_name, 
                              my_table_name,
                              Count_Null);

        if Count_Null = 0 then
            /* Only it inlcudes fields with not null values */
            set initial = initial + 1;

            if initial = 1 then
                SET allcols =  MYCOL;
            else                
                SET allcols  = concat( cast(allcols as char(255)), ',', MYCOL);
            end if;
        end if;
    END IF;

END LOOP read_cs_cur1;

close cs_cur1;

select allcols;
END
//
```

After, you may run as follows:

```
set delimiter ; 
call cur_cs_customer(@my_args, 'schema_name', 'users'); 
select @my_args; 
set @stm = concat('SELECT ', @my_args, ' FROM users;'); 
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @stm; 
execute stmt1; 
deallocate prepare stmt1;
```

Further explanation may be checked in [an article here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5264526/Get-a-customized-table-structure-with-non-null-fie)! .

I hope this tip may help you.

Comment: This will replace `None` with a different value, it won't remove them as requested.

Comment: That's correct, IsNull only replace with a different value, and you only need columns with not nulls values. It may be at least,i f one field has a not null value, this one counts as not null value, and, this one is expected to show too. I have improved the answer.